# Accessing struct pointer within another struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a type `node` whose pointer is being used in another struct as shown below.

```
typedef struct element {
    void* data;
    struct element *next;
} node;

typedef struct queue {
    node *tail;
    node *head;
    int num_items;
} queue_t;
```

I create an empty queue using the following code, but I am not sure if head and tail should be set to NULL since temp is not pointing anywhere yet.

```
queue_t *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
if (temp == NULL){
return NULL;
}
temp->head = NULL;
temp->tail = NULL;
temp->num_items = 0;
```

As per my understanding, `malloc` will only make temp point to some address space whose size is equal to the size of the `struct queue_t`. The address space does not contain a valid queue element yet. So how are *`temp->head = NULL;` and `temp->tail = NULL;`* valid statements?
Can someone please explain why this works?

Comment: If you say "C" in the title, don't tag with C++ too.  Choose a language; stick with it.

Comment: You don't have a `struct Node` in the code; you have a `struct element` also known as a `node`, and you have a `struct queue` also known as a `queue_t`.

Comment: You allocated a 'struct queue' (aka a queue_t), and then you set the values of the member variables in the struct you allocated.  Why wouldn't it work?  (Perhaps you read something about the bytes in the allocated space being undefined?  That's true, but it's only a problem if you *read* the undefined values, not if you overwrite them)

Answer (score 2):

> The address space does not contain a valid queue element yet.

Correct, the allocated memory only contains a `queue_t`

> So how are temp->head = NULL; and temp->tail = NULL; valid statements?

`head` and `tail` are not part of `struct element`. `head` and `tail` are part of `queue_t`. You have allocated a `queue_t` so it is OK to assign values to `head` and `tail`. In this case you assign the NULL value to show that they don't point to anything valid yet.

When you allocate a `node` (aka struct element) you update  `head` and `tail` like:

```
// Add first node
temp->head == malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->tail == temp->head;
if (temp->head == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
temp->num_items = 1;

// Initialize the new node
temp->head->next = NULL;   
temp->head->data = NULL;   

// Note: Adding more node requires more complex code
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of a "valid queue element"? If it's "sufficient space to hold a queue element and where the locations that hold the head and tail pointers have valid values", then setting them, to `NULL` makes it valid. If it's not that, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, `malloc` will only make temp point to some
>   address space whose size is equal to the size of the `struct queue_t`.

Correct.

> The address space does not contain a valid queue element yet.

Not sure what you what *you* meant by "valid", but that statement is also correct.

> So how are temp->head = NULL; and temp->tail = NULL; valid statements?

It is precisely those statements that makes your allocated space a valid queue element!

> Can someone please explain why this works?

Your question fundamentally is no different from a statement such as `int i;`.  Your implementation sets aside a space to hold an integer.  However, it is as yet invalid because you have not given it any (meaningful) value.  Once you set `i = 0;` or `i = 42;`, the space that you call `i` is now a valid integer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, malloc will only make temp point to some address space whose size is equal to the size of the struct queue_t.

The `malloc` function call returns an address to the beginning of the allocated memory of size specified in the argument of `malloc` function call(in bytes). The allocated memory space will be of size specified in the argument of the `malloc`. However, the address returned by `malloc` will be the beginning of that memory space. Therefore, you can access upto the size of the memory space safely using the pointer to that memory space.

> The address space does not contain a valid queue element yet.

The C Standard library has allocated a valid memory space for your pointer variable `temp` to point to. However, the values stored at that memory space could be garbage. Therefore, the pointer to `node` and `num_items` data members which have some valid memory space allocated to them within your `queue_t` may have garbage value. For example, after allocating the memory for `queue_t`, you can try to print the value of `num_items` using `printf` function.

```
queue_t *temp = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
if (temp == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
printf("The value of num_items: %d\n", temp->num_items);
```

The above example may print any garbage value. Since, `C language` doesn't have constructors to initialize newly created variables, you should initialize every variable you create with some stable value.

You can also use `calloc` function call which also sets allocated memory to `zero` after allocating the memory space.

> So how are temp->head = NULL; and temp->tail = NULL; valid statements?

The memory is allocated by `malloc` which may contain any garbage value. The data members of `queue_t` share that memory space. Since, memory space can have garbage data, the data members will be having any random garbage data. That's why it is a good approach to initialize `data members` of the struct allocated by `malloc` to some stable values. That's what you have done in your program.

Actually, `temp`'s data members `head` and `tail` should point to the addresses of variables of type `node`. The `malloc` call has allocated the `pointer variables`. These pointer variables can point to any variable of type `node` (or store the address of variable of type `node`). But you haven't allocated any `node` variable yet and you don't want to create `dangling pointer`. Therefore, you should initialize these `pointer variables` with `NULL`.

Your program should look like this:

```
queue_t *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
if (temp == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
temp->head = NULL;
temp->tail = NULL;
temp->num_items = 0;

//Allocate some node
node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
int data = 1;
n->data=&data;
n->next=NULL;
temp->head=n;
temp->tail=n;
temp->num_items=1;
```